# On angular 8 refreshing a page doesn't show the data from backend api

Tags: angular, firebase, django-rest-framework, firebase-authentication, angular8

I am fetching data from backend and showing it in a mat table, this table is rendered on a component inside a lazy loaded module. Everything seems to work fine until I refresh the page from the browser ( or it gets refreshed on its own while ng serve is running and I am coding, this was how I found the bug by the way).

On refreshing the page the data fetched from the API no longer shows. It works when navigating from a different page.

I am using Django rest framework at the backend to serve API to angular client.
My app authenticates the user in the backend using JWT and in the frontend uses firebase.

I am using Http interceptors to add the JWT token to all the Http request.

auth.service.ts to get token

```
getToken() {
   let tokenPromise = new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
    this.afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged( user => {

      if (user) {

        this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.getIdToken()
         .then(token => {
           this.userToken = token;
         });
      }

      if (this.userToken) {
        resolve(this.userToken);
      }

    });
   });

   return tokenPromise;

  }
```

api.service.ts to send http request

```
public getEmployees(): Observable<Employee[]> {
    return this.http.get<Employee[]>(`${this.url}/employee/`);
  }
```

token-interceptor.service.ts for adding the token

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TokenInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {


  constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

  intercept(req, next): Observable<any> {

    return from(this.authService.getToken()).pipe(
      switchMap(token => {
          const headers = req.headers
              .set('Authorization', 'JWT ' + token)
              .append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
          const reqClone = req.clone({
              headers
          });
          return next.handle(reqClone);
      }));
 }
}
```

On Chrome browser developer tool's network tab I can see that employee/ is fetched on normal navigation but when the browser is refreshed, employee/ is no longer there.

Comment: How/Where is the loading of the Employee-List triggered in your component?

Comment: Employee-List is inside the hrm module and hrm module is lazy loaded from the dashboard module. Dashboard module adds navigation components and therefore every module will be inside it, except signup, log in etc which is inside the fireauth directory and doesn't require the navigation components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the following line:
this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.getIdToken()

currenUser can be null and we need to afAuth.authState

The detailed answer can be found on the following link:

[How to fix "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getIdToken' of null" on browser refresh, in angular firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58625642/how-to-fix-typeerror-cannot-read-property-getidtoken-of-null-on-browser-ref)