# How to fix "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getIdToken' of null" on browser refresh, in angular firebase?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase in angular 8 to authenticate the user both in frontend and backend. To authenticate the user in the backend I need to send user Id token.

I am using firebase getIdToken to get the token and it works but partially. The error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getIdToken' of null" occurs when I refresh the page.

I have tried to hard code the token to the getToken() method and it works even on refresh but that is not feasible, so I made the getToken method to return Observable.

That observable is fetched in Http interceptor TokenInterceptorService, to add the token to all the requests.

```
export class AuthService {

  constructor(
    public afs: AngularFirestore,   // Inject Firestore service
    public afAuth: AngularFireAuth, // Inject Firebase auth service
    public router: Router,
    public ngZone: NgZone // NgZone service to remove outside scope warning
  ) {}


  // Other authentication methods for sign up etc.
  // removed here for readability


  getToken(): Observable<string> {

    // getIdToken() returns promise so using 'from' to 
    // convert it to an Observable
    const result = from(this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.getIdToken()
      .then( token => {
          console.log(token);
          return token;
      })
    );

    return result;
  }


}
```

```
export class TokenInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {


  constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }


  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    return this.authService.getToken()
      .pipe(
        switchMap(token => {

          const newRequest = request.clone({
            setHeaders: {Authorization: `JWT ${token}`}
          });

          return next.handle(newRequest);

        })
      );

 }

}
```

I have seen similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37934898/firebase-gettoken-typeerror-cannot-read-property) and I am using that solution with some modification.

I have even tried returning promise from getToken() method but that too doesn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

getting the `currentUser` is asynchronous, so it would be expected that initially it will be `null`. Like mentioned in [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user):

> Note: `currentUser` might also be null because the `auth` object has not finished initializing.

Instead you should be using `authState` to get the current user. Then from the user you get from there, you can call `getIdToken()`, which returns a promise. You can use `from` there to convert it to an observable:

```ts
getToken(): Observable<string | null> {
  return this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
    take(1),
    switchMap((user) => {
      if (user) {
        return from(user.getIdToken())
      }
      return of(null);
    })
  )
}
```

Then in your interceptor, also do a check if token exists. If there is no user, it will return `null`

Comment: This seems hacky... is this a good way of doing it?

Comment: Sorry for the extremely delayed answer @Xanlantos . If you check the link I shared from documentation, it explicitly says ```The recommended way to get the current user is by setting an observer on the Auth object```, so this is definitely not a hack, but exactly what they suggest we should do.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using the latest angular 17 and you're looking for suggestions and also if you're using a functional interceptor then you can create your interceptor something like this:-

this is my interceptor

```
import { HttpInterceptorFn } from '@angular/common/http';
import { inject } from '@angular/core';
import { authService } from '../auth.service';
import { switchMap, pipe } from 'rxjs';

export const appendPropertiesInterceptor: HttpInterceptorFn = (req, next) => {
  const authService = inject(AuthService);

  return authService.getFireToken().pipe(
    switchMap((token: any) => {
      let authRequest = req;

      if (
        !req.url.includes('https://storage.googleapis.com') &&
        !req.url.includes('https://hooks.slack.com')
      ) {
        authRequest = authRequest.clone({
          headers: req.headers
            .set('x-token', token)
        });
      }

      return next(authRequest);
    })
  );
};
```

this is my function which I have added in auth service.

```
    import { Observable, Subject, catchError, from, of, switchMap } from 'rxjs';
    import { Auth } from '@angular/fire/auth';


    export class AuthService {
    getFireToken(): Observable<string> {
        const currentUser = this.auth.currentUser;
        if (!currentUser) {
          return of('');
        }
        const result: Observable<string> = from(currentUser.getIdToken()).pipe(
          switchMap((token: string) => {
            console.log(token);
            return of(token);
          }),
          catchError((error: any) => {
            console.error('Error getting the token:', error);
            return of(''); 
          })
        );
        return result;
      }
    }
```