# How to inject a dependency in HttpInterceptorFn in angular 17?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, interceptor, angular-http-interceptors

Here is my interceptor using the new way of intercept of angular, using a function instead of a class

```
export const errorInterceptor: HttpInterceptorFn = (req, next) => {
  console.log('Intercepted');
  return next(req);
};
```

But in this interceptor I want to use the Router class to navigate my user, but I do not have access to my constructor to inject since it's a function.

Use Dependency injection in the new way of intercepting using HttpInterceptorFn in angular 17

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77840978/how-to-use-functional-interceptor-for-refreshing-token-in-angular-17/77841238#77841238

Answer (score 5):

Just simply inject it inline with the `inject()` method.

I modified you're code. In the following example both the the `Router` and a custom `AuthenticationService` is injected into the method, then they can be used in the scope of the given method.

```
import { inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

export const errorInterceptor: HttpInterceptorFn = (req, next) => {
  const router = inject(Router);
  const authService = inject(AuthenticationService);
  console.log('Intercepted');
  return next(req).pipe(
    catchError((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      if (err.status === 401) {
        console.log('authInterceptor 401');
        authService.logout();
        router.navigate(['/auth/signout']);
      }
      return throwError(() => new Error('Unauthorized Exception'));
    })
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you bro, I don't know why is there any question about this on internet

Comment: This gives error
inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with `runInInjectionCont